# Which is the best way or method to prevent session fixation and highjacking in php ?

Tags: php, security, session

I browsed various **method to prevent session fixation and highjacking** in php but I am finding it difficult to figure out which is the best way on which I can rely on . Like to prevent sql injection most of the developer suggest use of prepare statement .It is effective in preventing most of the sql injection attacks . Is there any such code , function or snippet availble best,quick and simple in regard to prevent attack on session . Please share it . 
Thank you all .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a few things you can do to help such as, when setting cookies set them to httponly so they are not able to be read from javascript, keep track of a users ip address and only allow access to the session if the users ip is within a certain range of the ip they started the session with, when starting a new session regenerate session id instead of reusing a previous one , keep track of the users browser and if that changes during a session do not allow access to the session. I am sure there are more but thats just off the top pf my head.

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow http protocol, only https.

That's it, it prevents SESSID hijackings...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://yourdomain.com/ [R]
```

Comment: This is exactly what online banks and similar sites do.

Comment: @yi_H: ridiculous? What's wrong on it?

Comment: let's take an example: -"How can I make my computer secure?" -"Unplug the power cord". Does that solve the problem? Yes. Is the answer useful for the OP? No. (and no, I'm not suggesting that you said he has to unplug the cord. I'm just saying it's ridiculous)

Comment: There is no ridiculous answer regarding information security.This solution provides one of the best ways to secure your session cookie. If you really need to prevent session theft, for instance if a stolen session would cost you more money than a ssl certificate, this is a really valid solution.